# How to Track User Activity in angular 4/5/6

Tags: angular5, angular6, tracking, user-activity

In Angular 4/5/6 is there any library which helps to track User Activity?

The most obvious way to track/log user activity would be to save all HTTP requests and parameters along with the username into the database.

EDIT: I would like to track things like 1) Bob clicked 'Add New Customer' button on the Customers page 2) Bob has updated the customer information.
3) Krish as executed so XYZ Report etc.

Sno    Name        Timestamp              Log
   1     Bob     29-10-18 3:39:11PM  add a new customer

Tracking what actions were performed by what users is essential, so something like google analytics does not really fit the bill. Because google analytics only showing up the routing details but not actions

if not library what is the best solution?

Note: Please if you downvote, let me know what is wrong with my question

Answer (score 1):

if you want to track user's activity then you have to install "**angular2piwik**"

```
npm install angular2piwik --save
```

Comment: Can you add more details on why or what the tool does?